# Is it possible to extend $f(z)=\frac{\Re(z)}{|z|}$ by continuity at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-numbers, continuity

> Is it possible to extend $f(z)=\frac{\Re(z)}{|z|}$ by continuity at $z=0$?

Let $z=r(\cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta))$. Then $\frac{\Re(z)}{|z|} = \frac{r \cos(\theta)}{r} = \cos(\theta) $; as the limit will not depend of $r$, so $f$ can't be extend by continuity.

Am I right?

Comment: Almost right: “the limit depends on $\theta$” is the correct argument.

Comment: I think $r \neq 0$ if you let $\theta \to 0$. I think the trick to these problems is define the discontinuity at its limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is $\frac{\Re (z)}{z}$ continuous at $z=0$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804891/is-frac-re-zz-continuous-at-z-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is not correct: also in $g(z)=z/z$ the limit does not depend on $r$, but the function can obviously be extended by continuity.

The idea of using the polar form is good, though. But it's easier if you try approaching $0$ along the real axis, where the function is constantly $1$, and along the imaginary axis, where the function is constantly $0$.

Comment: @CristhianDavis Almost. If $z\ne 0$ belongs to the real axis, then $f(z)=1$; if $z\ne0$ belongs to the imaginary axis, then $f(z)=0$. Since $0$ is an accumulation point of both the real and the imaginary axes, the limit cannot exist.